# IA86 ASM Code Reading

Tags: assembly

I'm having a hard time deciphering what the ASM code below is supposed to do... any direction would be great!

```
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp
 movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
 movl 12(%ebp), %esi
 movl $0, %ecx
 L1:
movl (%ebx, %ecx, 4), %edi
 cmpl $100, %edi
 jl L2
movl $100, (%ebx, %ecx, 4)
 jmp L3
 L2:
 cmpl $-100, %edi
 jg L3
movl $-100, (%ebx, %ecx, 4)
 L3:
addl $1, %ecx
cmpl %ecx, %esi
jne L1
leave
ret
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a function that takes two arguments - a pointer to an array of integers and size. It goes through the array, and replaces all values that are over 100 with 100, and the ones that are below -100 with -100.

Comment: How would one go about editing that code to accept an input like x and -x instead of just 100 and -100?

Comment: Read up on the C calling convention. Two more int arguments would be on the stack at 16(ebp) and 20(epb). Load them into registers and use them in the loop instead of constants.